# Web2py commit error

Tags: web2py

I'm new on web2py and I've created an app that's pretty much a cloned of the example that comes with the program. When I committed it gives me this error: Internal error

Ticket issued: admin/107.184.217.20.2017-02-19.06-11-34.a3fa2454-79b4-4f96-b120-f77645a5a35f

Could someone please help me fix it, I have no idea how to even start. thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "when I committed it"? Are you able to access that ticket or access the admin app at all?

Comment: I meant commit changes through versioning(version control), it issued me that ticket. And yes I can access my admin app, but I am made another app that I am practicing on.

Comment: Can you get to the ticket in question (i.e., click the link)? If so, what does the traceback say?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Kash40k/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/Kash40k/web2py/applications/admin/controllers/mercurial.py", line 87, in <module>
  File "/home/Kash40k/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 417, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/home/Kash40k/web2py/applications/admin/controllers/mercurial.py", line 50, in commit
    addremove(repo)
TypeError: addremove() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the internal API of Mercurial changed but web2py was not updated: https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1245.

So, for now, this functionality of the admin app is broken. You should make your Mercurial commits via some other means.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I suspect that the error might be caused by the incomparability with the current Python version, in my case, 3.6.